# Problem with including a file

Tags: php

i am getting this error

```
[28-Jan-2011 09:49:03] PHP Warning:  require_once(../../includes/database.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/photo/application/php/classes/users.php on line 2
```

[28-Jan-2011 09:49:03] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../../includes/database.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/photo/application/php/classes/users.php on line 2

The file i would like to include is in

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/photo/application/includes/database.php
```

I am sure the file is there, i have checked, double checked, triple checked
This is the line 2 in users.php

```
require_once '../../includes/database.php';
```

What could be the problem

Comment: Print out ``pwd`` right before require_once to see what directory you are actually in.

Comment: @pascal: doesnt look like it..

Comment: You can try this, `require_once (dirname(__FILE__).'/../../includes/database.php'); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this at the main file (e.g. index.php)

```
define('BASEPATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

and then

```
require_once(BASEPATH.'../../includes/database.php');
```

Working with full paths is always a good idea.

ps: it was an example, the path might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The default include path is relative to the **calling** file (`.` is the path).

Example dir structure:

```
index.php
foo.php
bar.php
/assets/foo.php
       /bar.php
```

if your `index.php` calls

```
include 'assets/foo.php';
```

and `one/foo.php` calls

```
include 'bar.php';
```

it will be equivalent to `index.php` calling

```
include 'assets/bar.php';
```

If you want your includes to all come from the same context, you'll need to use a root-relative path (@yoda has a good example of this).